# I need help setting up a github webhook with a localhost jenkins

Tags: git, github, jenkins, localhost, hook

I have:
   - a public github repository
   - a localhost:8080 jenkins
   - a java maven project connected to the github repository
   - a jenkins job connected to the github repo
I am able to trigger manual builds anytime, but I want to have a build triggered at each commit pushed to the github repository.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that your localhost Jenkins server (without any public IP address) is sitting behind a firewall and/or NAT, so the GitHub webhook cannot be delivered to your localhost Jeninks server.

In order to make your public GitHub repository talk to your localhost Jenkins server (behind the firewall and NAT etc) you need to use a free  webhook proxy service called [SocketXP](https://www.socketxp.com).  SocketXP helps create a secure webhook relay tunnel between the Public GitHub and your Private Jenkins server through which SocketXP will proxy the webhook notification from the public GitHub to your localhost Jenkins.

SocketXP will create a unique public URL for your Jenkins server which you could use to configure the GitHub Webhook settings later.

Here are the 3 simple steps involved to install and run SocketXP on your Jenkins server:

**Step #1:**

Sign up for a free account with [SocketXP](https://portal.socketxp.com/#/login).  Get a unique JWT auth token assigned just for you.

**Step #2**:

Download a simple, lightweight SocketXP agent from [here](https://www.socketxp.com/download/) and install it on the same localhost machine where Jenkins is running. Please note that you need to install this on the host machine where Jenkins is also running.

Use the JWT auth token from step #1 to login to SocketXP agent using the following command:

```sh
$ socketxp login < your-auth-token >
```

**Step #3:**

Get a unique public URL for your localhost Jenkins server using the following command.

```sh
$ socketxp relay https://localhost:8080/github-webhook/
```

```
Public URL ->  https://webhook.socketxp.com/adfasdfae4123-webhook-relay
```

Use the above unique **public URL** (created just for your localhost jenkins server) to configure your GitHub webhook settings.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to start a build when a change is pushed to GitHub you need to configure the Github's Webhook: 
Head over to the GitHub repo and click Settings. Click the Webhooks & Services tab, and then the Add service drop-down. Select the Jenkins (GitHub plugin) service.
And finally, your Jenkins hook url:

```
http://JENKINS.SERVER.IP.ADDRESS:8080/github-webhook/
```

Therefore, you need a public IP address or DNS for allowing GitHub to trigger your Jenkins build.

Answer (score 2):

There is an option in jenkins under "Build Triggers" where you can check off the "Build when a change is pushed to GitHub". This will poll the github repository for any change. If any change is found, a build will be triggered automatically.

[image: Build Triggers]

You can configure the schedule to poll SCM as well.

Comment: The option  "Build when a change is pushed to GitHub" is checked but no build is triggered, and that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: Did you setup the config for git under "Source code management"? Could you please update your question with a screenshot of the jenkins config that you have?

Comment: you have the wrong repository url, it should end with `.git`.

I think this is what you are looking for `https://github.com/gneamt/mavg.git`